# Which asp.net control could be used for binding one EF object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, controls

When I want to get more rows from MainTable, I'm using GridView with property SelectMethod so I can access data from every table that is connected to MainTable with FK like (inside gridview)

```
<asp:Label ID="masRegionNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%#:Item.Region.RegionName %>'></asp:Label>
```

Here I can access column RegionName that is part of table Region that is connected with MainTable using navigation (FK RegionId in MainTable).

What I want now is to let every record have own detail page, where I can show more detailed info about chosen record.

My question is if there is any control in asp.net where I could bind one single EF object and access data similarly like in GridView.

First option was that GridView that showed me just one record, but it is not best for design. The second time I have tryed to load desired instance of MainTable in codebehind, but I in this case I can access only fields that are physically in MainTable, ex. I can access MainTable.Name but I can't access MainTable.Region.RegionName. When I try to access this field it gives me following error:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I wonder if I could have some control where I just bind one object - MainTable with some method and in this control I could do some html css design and access (view,edit) all data related to specific record that are constantly binded. Or is there at least something better than GridView for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

This error means that you are trying to access the context after it has been disposed (as the error states quite clearly :)) EF uses lazy loading for navigation properties. So what is happning is that you are accessing a navigation property and EF needs to get the data from the context, but the context does not exist any more.

There are two options:

1. You need to recreate the context or not dispose of it to begin with
   before you make this call.
2. You can tell EF to load this navigation property eagerly, instead of lazily.

You can accomplish 2 by using the `Include()` method, which instructs EF to load the chosen navigation property eagerly. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

**EDIT:** If you would like to turn lazy loading off, you can do it per-property by not marking the navigation property as `virtual` or at the context level by adding this code to the constructor:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public MyContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But one more question is it possible to somehow use include with object instead od string path? I'm trying to access everything that is related to db in objects so I could simply update edmx model instead of rewriting strings when something in db would changed.

Comment: And to complete this answer, there is a component in ASP.NET for single db record called `DetailsView`.

Comment: There is a generic version of include in `DbExtensions` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: I edited my post with further information about disabling lazy loading.